# Is there a class to signify "grouped by and reduced"?

Tags: scalding

consider the following code in Scalding:

Let's say I have the following tuples in a scalding `TypedPipe[(Int, Int)]`:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
```

On this pipe I can call `groupBy(t => t._1)` to generate a `Grouped[Int, (Int, Int)]` , which will still represent the same data, but grouped by the 1st item of the tuple.

Now, let's say I sum the resulting object, so the total flow is like that:

```
def sumGroup(a : TypedPipe[(Int, Int)]) : Grouped[Int, (Int, Int)] =
    {
    a.groupBy(t => t._1).sum
    }
```

The result of doing this on the initial example would result in the following tuples:

```
(1, (2, 5))
(2  (4, 3))
```

And now we know for sure that there is only one item per key (for the key "1", we only have one resulting tuple) because this is the behavior of `sum`. However the type returned by sum is still `Grouped[Int, (Int, Int)]`, which doesn't convey the fact that there can only be one item per key.

Is there a specific type like `Grouped[K, V]` that would convey the meaning that there is only one "V" value for a given "K" value ? If not, why is that?

It seems it could be useful to optimize joins when we can be sure that both sides exactly have one value per key.